# VBScript If then, trying to run exe with arguments

Tags: vbscript, if-statement

```
Option Explicit 

Dim oFSO, oTxtFile

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

If oFSO.FileExists("c:\users\Installed.txt")  Then
  WScript.Quit
Else 
  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WshShell.Exec("\\1.1.1.1\software\1.exe -s /s -a ns=1.5.3.2")   

  Set oTxtFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\users\Installed.txt") 
End If
```

My Code is above. I am getting an error when running my vbs. Line 13 char 1 variable is undefined. "WSHShell".

The goal is to have this vbs check for a file. If the file exists then end. If the file is not found run an installer with arguments, then create the file.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use "Option Explicit" - as you should - all variables must be (Re)Dim-ed. So add WshShell to you Dim statement.